# Tailwind active style not displaying when element is also hovered

Tags: html, css, laravel, tailwind-css

I am working with TailwindCSS and am making a simple button that I want to have a shadow when hovered, then scale down when focused or active. The hover style works, but the active style does not. However it does work when I click it and then move the mouse off the button.

Button:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'createEvent'}" tag="button" class="w-1/6 mx-auto rounded-full font-semibold py-2 px-4 border border-white rounded text-blue-400 bg-white hover:shadow-lg focus:bounce-sm hover:translate-t-2px transition-fast">
   Get Started
</router-link>
```

CSS:

```
/*scale*/
@variants responsive, hover, focus, active {
    .bounce-sm {
       transform: scale(0.95);
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

Hover works
[image]

Focus does not work when hover is also on
[image]

But focus works when hover is not on
[image]

Could someone explain to me why this is and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Could you put the relevant code in a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/)? Element states are tough to troubleshoot without a working example.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add `Pseudo-Class Variant` for `boxShadow` to your `tailwind.js` file in `variants` object.

It would look like this:

```js
variants: {
   boxShadow: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus'],  
},
```

This will allow you to tweak `boxShadow` based on responsive classes, hover or focus.

I hope it helps.

Resources: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants/#app